# UITableView with multiple sections loads choppy

Tags: ios, uitableview, grand-central-dispatch

I have a `UITableView` (TV) with several sections, each section has an `NSArray` that serves as the dataSource (no CoreData, no images). When the user opens the TV, my app does some intensive calculations to generate the dataSource arrays. In some cases, the calculations can take some time, and what happens then is that the section headers show first, after which the cells appear, which doesn't like good, I think.

I'm already using GCD to do the calculations:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear: animated];

    [MBProgressHUD showHUDForView: self.view animated: YES];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
        [self.model generateData];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView: self.view animated: YES];

            [self.tableView reloadData];
        });
    });
}
```

Besides trying to optimize the calculations, is there anything else I could do to make this look smoother? For instance, is there a way for the section headers not to appear until the calculations are done?

**UPDATE:**

So in the end, my solution turned out to be different. To generate my data I am now using a `dispatch_group`, and calculate the`NSArray` for each section in an`dispatch_group_async` block, so they run concurrently. This already was an improvement in speed. Furthermore, I start the calculation already in the `UIViewController` from which the user opens the TV. Therefore, the data is available almost instantly when the TV opens, and all sections load smoothly.

Here is a code snippet for completeness:

```
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

dispatch_group_async(group, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0) ^{
    [self.model generateArray1];
});

dispatch_group_async(group, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0) ^{
    [self.model generateArray2];
});

//... etc for each section

// make sure that everything is done before moving on

dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you return `nil` from `tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:` then the header won't be shown, so add a small amount of conditional logic which checks if the data is loaded yet and either returns `nil` (if not loaded) or the section title (if it is loaded).

Comment: This put me on the right track. I am also looking into `tableView:willDisplayHeaderView:forSection:`, but have not yet decided what will be the best fit.

Comment: After much trying with this approach, unfortunately, the cells for the different sections will still appear in chunks as each becomes available. Even without the missing headers, it still doesn't look good, I think. So just for completeness, my plan now is to calculate all arrays concurrently, and not call `[self.tableView reloadData]` until they are all done. I think in the end this will look much smoother, even with the delay. I will post the updated code once I'm happy with it.